# Highlighting words and then unhighlighting using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that will highlight a word in a textbox, however, what I would like to be able to achieve is when the same word is clicked again the word will then be unhighlighted. Is this possible? Below is the section of code that does stuff when a word is clicked. I hope you are able to help.

```
def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="none")
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.text.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self._on_click)
        self.text.tag_configure("highlight", background="green", foreground="black")

        with open(__file__, "rU") as f:
            data = f.read()
            self.text.insert("1.0", data)

def _on_click(self, event):
            self.text.tag_add("highlight", "insert wordstart", "insert wordend")
```

I have attempted it by using:

```
def _on_click(self, event):
    self.text.tag_remove("highlight", "1.0", "end")
    self.text.tag_add("highlight", "insert wordstart", "insert wordend")
    if self.text.tag_names == ('sel', 'highlight'):
        self.text.tag_add("highlight", "insert wordstart", "insert wordend")
    else:
        self.text.tag_remove("highlight", "1.0", "end")
```

but that has no luck.

Comment: Please show what you've actually tried, not just a paraphrase of some code. Also, if you haven't tried it, use `tag_remove` to remove the "highlight" tag.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have added the details you have requested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tag_names` to get a list of tags at a certain index. Then it's just a matter of calling `tag_add` or `tag_remove` depending on whether the tag is present on the current word or not.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.text = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self._on_click)
        self.text.tag_configure("highlight", background="bisque")

        with open(__file__, "r") as f:
            self.text.insert("1.0", f.read())

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def _on_click(self, event):
        tags = self.text.tag_names("insert wordstart")
        if "highlight" in tags:
            self.text.tag_remove("highlight", "insert wordstart", "insert wordend")
        else:
            self.text.tag_add("highlight", "insert wordstart", "insert wordend")

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    Example().start()
```

Comment: Life saver! Thank you :)