# Adding words to a list when the word is clicked on in a textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

Ideally the user will type in some text into a scrolledtext widget. When this is done, the user will go into setting mode and  select the key words. These key words will then go into an array. 
I have managed to create the gui and the 'settings' mode but I do not know how to get it so when the word is clicked the word selected will be added to a list. Here is what I have started with to decide if it is in setting mode or not as well as binding the _on_click_ to the textbox.

```
ArticleTextBox.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", _on_click)

def _on_click(event):
    state = str(namebutton['state'])
    if state != 'disabled':
```

Thanks in advance for your help and if you have any questions feel free to ask them :)

Comment: You've already asked a couple questions about highlighting words in a text widget. How is this question different? You've been shown how to highlight a word when clicked, so what problem are you having in getting that word and adding it to a  list?

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I currently have NLTK to highlight all the names in a document but because NLTK sometimes misses some names or even highlights words that aren't names I then want the user to be able to edit these highlights so they can select the names missed. When the user has selected the word I then want it to be added to the list that has all the names. So I do not know how to add the new highlighted word to a list. I Hope that makes sense. P.S. I am still fairly new to python

Comment: _"I do not know how to add the new highlighted word to a list"_ - can you be more specific? Why can't you simply do `the_list.append(new_word)`?

Answer (score 0):

I saw answer to your previous question [Highlighting words and then unhighlighting using tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47339945/1832058) and to get clicked text you can do:

```
def _on_click(self, event):
    word = self.text.get("insert wordstart", "insert wordend")
    print(word)
```

so now you can add it to your list.