# tkinter highlight words by button clicks in Scrolledtext

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to move to the next found word in the Scrolledtext and highlight it. The function finds indexes, but somehow I don't see the highlighting. The word is always the same. The search is in the dictionary text. There are usually many instances of the same word in the dictionary. The function **see()** is tied to a button. I use the **highlight_word()** in another function that is called **see()**, that function allows to move from word to word in the Scrolledtext and updates count of the words in a label. And this combination of functions does not work together...

UPDATE.
Thanks to hints from Bryan Oakley and in particular his hint which I found here. [text.tag_remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339287/highlighting-words-and-then-unhighlighting-using-tkinter) The script now does what I want: it highlights the found word, and when the next found word is highlighted the highlight on the previous word is removed.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as TkFont
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
root = tk.Tk()

customFont = TkFont.Font(family="Fira Code", size=28)

var = tk.StringVar()

root.configure(bg='#3541b7')

root.geometry("1800x1000")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

show = tk.IntVar()
show.set(0)
countVar = tk.StringVar()
idxVar = tk.StringVar()
posis = []

text = ScrolledText(root, width=140, height=400, wrap=WORD)
text.configure(background="#3f3f3f", fg='#dcdccc', font=customFont)
text.grid(row=1, columnspan=20,  sticky=N + S + W + E)

text_to_search = '''
tempo
tempo
tempo
'''

text.insert(END, text_to_search)

entry_newwindow = tk.Entry(root, font=('Arial', 30), bg="#ffc299", bd=2)

IDX = "1.0"
prev_IDX = ""
prev_lastIDX = ""    

def highlight_word():
  global IDX
  global prev_IDX
  global prev_lastIDX
  prev_IDX = ""
  word = entry_newwindow.get().strip()
  IDX = text.search(word, IDX, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
  prev_IDX = IDX
  lastIDX = '%s+%dc' % (IDX, len(word))
  prev_lastIDX = lastIDX
  text.tag_add('word', IDX, lastIDX)
  text.tag_config('word', background='blue')
  IDX = lastIDX

    
def see():
    word = entry_newwindow.get().strip()
    pos = show.get()
    lbl_Count.config(text=f'{pos + 1}')
    if prev_IDX and prev_lastIDX:
        text.tag_remove("word", prev_IDX, prev_lastIDX)
    highlight_word()
    show.set(pos + 1)
  

btn_see = tk.Button(root, text='Find', fg='white', bg='#1E7056', font=(
    'Fira Code', 21), borderwidth=' 4', command=see)

lbl_Count = tk.Label(root, font=('Fira Code bold', 24),
                     bg="#81cbfe", borderwidth=4, width=3, relief="groove", text="0")

entry_newwindow.grid(column=0, row=0,sticky="we")
entry_newwindow.focus_set()
btn_see.grid(column=1, row=0)
lbl_Count.grid(column=2, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me. When I call the function with a word in the entry widget, that word is highlighted in blue. Please provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: This still isn't a complete program. We don't know how you create the text widget, or how you call these functions. Plus, `see` uses objects (`show`, `lbl_Count`) that you haven't defined anywhere.

Comment: @BryanOakley. You are right.... I have added all the code that may clarify things.

Comment: That code has indentation errors. There also seems to be several lines of code that aren't necessary to reproduce the problem. Please try to make sure it is both minimal and runnable.

Comment: @BryanOakley. Now all is fixed. It's now a minimal working example. Alas, not highlighting the words in the Scrolledtext.

Comment: When I run this code, a "^" appears at the start of the entry widget. Why is that? Are you attempting to search on a regular expression, or are you expecting to search for a literal "^", or something else? Are you thinking that `text.search` by default searches for regular expressions?

Comment: @BryanOakley. Other functions use that caret sigh for reg expressions. Now the script works. Thanks for the numerous hints!

Comment: Yes, the caret is used in regular expressions. However, by default the `search` method does not consider the search string to be a regular expression. It will look for a literal caret character. Searching for `^tempo` in your example will not find any matches.